# Trouble sending string over socket in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, websocket

So I am using sockets in Android to establish a connection and then send strings from an EditText field using a send_message button in the UI.

I can establish the connection, however, when I try and send a message using `sendMessage`, both the Client and Server Threads go to the catch part of the statement. In the code refer to:

- On the server thread: "Oops. Connection interrupted. Please reconnect your phones."
- On the client thread: "except"

I saw in other StackOverflow threads that it may have to do with the `PrintWriter out` variable and it's scope?

Would love your help and feedback

```
package com.project.jaja.fleetcommander;
import com.project.jaja.fleetcommander.util.SystemUiHider;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Inet4Address;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class P2PActivity extends Activity {

    //Omitting non-relevant code to with fullscreen

    private TextView serverStatus;

    // Client IP
    public String CLIENTIP;

    // SERVER IP
    public String SERVERIP = "10.0.2.15";
    // DESIGNATE A PORT
    public static final int SERVERPORT = 5554;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

    private EditText serverIpField;

    private boolean connected = false;
    private boolean hosting = false;
    public Button sendMessage;

    public PrintWriter out = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_p2p);
        serverIpField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.server_ip);
        serverStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.server_status);
        sendMessage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_button);

         //Omitting non-relevant code to do with fullscreen

    }

    //Omitting non-relevant code to do with fullscreen

    public void clickServer(View view) {
        SERVERIP = getLocalIpAddress();
        Thread fst = new Thread(new ServerThread());
        fst.start();
        hosting = true;

        Button serverButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.server_button);
        serverButton.setEnabled(false);
    }

    public void clickClient(View view) {
        if (!connected) {
            SERVERIP = serverIpField.getText().toString();
            CLIENTIP = getLocalIpAddress();
            if (!SERVERIP.equals("")) {
                Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
                cThread.start();
            }
        }
    }

    public class ServerThread implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            try {
                if (SERVERIP != null) {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            serverStatus.setText("Listening on IP: " + SERVERIP);
                        }
                    });
                    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
                    while (true) {
                        // LISTEN FOR INCOMING CLIENTS
                        Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                        CLIENTIP = client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                serverStatus.setText("Connected.");
                            }
                        });

                        try {
                            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                            String line = null;
                            out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);

                            sendMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    EditText message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message_field);
                                    out.println(message.getText().toString());
                                    message.setText("");
                                }
                            });

                            connected = true;
                            while (connected) {
                                line = in.readLine();

                                if (line.equals("GAME END")) {
                                    serverSocket.close();
                                } else {
                                    serverStatus.setText(line);
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    serverStatus.setText("Oops. Connection interrupted. Please reconnect your phones.");
                                }
                            });
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            serverStatus.setText("Couldn't detect internet connection.");
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        serverStatus.setText("Error");
                    }
                });
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    // GETS THE IP ADDRESS OF YOUR PHONE'S NETWORK
    public static String getLocalIpAddress() {
        try {
            for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
                NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
                for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                    InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                    if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress() && inetAddress instanceof Inet4Address) {
                        return inetAddress.getHostAddress();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        try {
            // MAKE SURE YOU CLOSE THE SOCKET UPON EXITING
            if (serverSocket != null) {
                serverSocket.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class ClientThread implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);
                try {
                    Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
                    connected = true;
                    while (connected) {
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                        String input = in.readLine();
                        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

                        sendMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                EditText message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message_field);
                                out.println(message.getText().toString());
                                message.setText("");
                            }
                        });

                        if (input.equals("GAME END")) {
                            connected = false;
                        } else {
                            serverStatus.setText(input);
                        }
                    }
                    socket.close();
                    serverStatus.setText("socket closed");
                    Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Closed.");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        serverStatus.setText("except");
                        Log.e("ClientActivity", "S: Error", e);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ClientActivity", "C: Error", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially, the code aims not to distinguish too much between the client and server.

Comment: If they catch part of the statement then you know the exact catch and you could tell us. It seems that in the on click handlers you use the outputstream out on the main thread. That sending should be done in a thread too. Furter you have several editText.setText() not in a run on ui thread. You have client and server in one activity. Dou you use two instances of your app?

Comment: Yeah, two separate instances. I'll try and put it all in a thread and see. Thanks :)